# Word for something showing a multitude of issues on a smaller scale

Tags: single-word-requests

The word is used to describe something (a single unit) which can be used to show a multitude of issues on a smaller scale. For example, a company which shows everything that is wrong with capitalism. Sort of like an analogy.

Comment: This needs a whole lot more info to get near any word or phrase. You should also give a sentence with a blank in it.

Answer (score 4):

**Microcosm**, which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/microcosm?locale=en) defines as "A community, place, or situation regarded as encapsulating in miniature the characteristics of something much larger."

Answer (score 1):

***Exemplar*** may fit your context:

> a person or thing serving as a typical example or appropriate model.
>
> - "the place is an exemplar of multicultural Britain"